# Expression Engine image:url not replaced on style attr

Tags: tags

Is there a escape mechanism for strings in EE to render EE tags?
This is my snippet

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="used_vehicles" paginate="top"}
{paginate}
    {pagination_links page_padding="2"}
{/paginate}
<article>
    <a href="{permalink='site/usado'}" class="car">
      <div class="image_holder" style="background-image: url({image:url:medium})"></div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <span class="ver_mas">Ver más</span>
    </a>
</article>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I need that {image:url:medium} be replaced by the entry's image url. But on the inspector it seems it only puts {image:url:medium}. Any ideas?

**edit:**
Forgot to say that, sadly, I can't change the div to an img tag.

Comment: What @Jelle Dijkstra said, good gentelperson, are you using channel images or another addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using channel images syntax. Are you using that addon? or do you have a native file field? if you are using native you should be using a tag pair like this:

```
{image}
<div class="image_holder" style="background-image: url({url:medium})"></div>
{/image}
```

Just one other thing: you'll get the best EE answers on http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com